# ¿Como recibir correo con datos del formulario usando PHPMailer?

Tags: php, html5, php7, phpmailer

Tengo un formulario html simple que envía dos datos nombre y apellido. Mi proveeedor de hosting tiene configurado en el servidor la versión 7.2 y estoy usando este repositorio de phpmailer  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.

El formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="form-contacto" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre Completo</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" onkeypress="return alfabetico(event);">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
        <label for="nombre">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido" onkeypress="return alfabetico(event);">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary pill px-4 py-2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Para validar los datos uso jquery.validate y hago mis validaciones en con el siguiente script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#enviar").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#form-contacto").submit();
    });

    $("#form-contacto").validate({
        rules: {
            nombre: {
                required: true
            },
            apellido: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            nombre: "Ingrese Nombre",
            apellido: "Ingrese Apellido"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#enviar').attr("disabled", true);
            enviarForm();
        }   
    });
});

function enviarForm(){
    var parametros = {
        nombre: $('#nombre').val(),
        email: $('#apellido').val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:  'procesar.php',
        type:  'POST',
        async: false,
        success:  function (response) {
            // document.location.href = "legales.html"; 
            alert ("Tus datos se enviaron de forma exitosa!");
        },
        error : showError
    });
}
```

Al momento de presionar enviar se realizan las validaciones sin problemas y se activa la función "enviarForm" la cual manda los datos a mi archivo procesar.php el cual contiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];

require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);           // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {

    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
    $mail->Port       = 465;             // TCP port to connect to

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = "Formulario contacto";
    $mail->Body    = "
    <b>Nombre: </b>" . strip_tags($_POST['nombre']) . "<br />
    <b>Apellido: </b>" . strip_tags($_POST['apellido']) . "<br />";

    $mail->setFrom($email);
    $mail->addAddress('micorreo@gmail.com');


    $mail->send();
    echo 'El mensaje se envio de manera exitosa';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'No se pudo enviar el correo: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}}

else
{
    echo "mensaje no enviado";
}?>
```

Cuando inspecciono elemento y veo en network el me responde error 500 y no me llega el correo con los datos ingresados por los usuarios.

Al ver el apartado de Form Data puedo ver que se están mandando bien los datos del formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi teoria de mi error son las siguientes:

1. Pienso que puede ser porque falla algo de mi archivo procesar.php
2. Creo que puede ser porque falta habilitar algún modulo en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

yo hice algo igual ahora muestro como fue que estructure mi codigo

```
$mail->setFrom('solsismailer@gmail.com', 'Soluciones con Sisitemas');
$mail->addAddress("solsis502.gt@gmail.com", 'Soluciones con Sistemas');                   $mail->addAddress($mail_destino,$nombre_cliente);    
$mail->isHTML(true);             
$mail->Subject = 'Contraraciones, NO RESPONDER ESTE MENSAJE';
$mail->Body = $mensaje_enviar;
$mail->send();
```

Recuerda poder activar el incio de sesion inseguro en tu correo.